# viewHolder could not be cast by viewHolder

Tags: android, listview, view, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I'm trying to display 2 different item views depending on what I have in my Array list. Without the condition (if) there is no problem, but when I put the condition and so I have to deal with 2 viewHolders I get an error telling that viewHolder cannot be cast by viewHolder.

Here is my code :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

   bind(getItem(position), view);

   return view;
}


private void bind(final Eddystone eddystone, final View view) {

      List<Content> contents = ... ; 

      if(contents.get(i).content_type_id==2){

           ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
           // some code here
      }
      else {

          ViewHolderVideo holder = (ViewHolderVideo) view.getTag();
          // some code here
      }

}
```

the error is on the second holder (in else condition).

Please remember when I remove the condition (the else) it works perfectly, and the class where this code is written is an adapter.

Please any help is welcome.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is ListView is recycling the wrong row. Currently ListView thinks all rows are the same, because you haven't told it that there are more than one type of row.

Your adapter needs to implement [`getItemViewType()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) and [`getViewTypeCount()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount()). These two methods inform `ListView` of the number of types of rows and which row types correspond to which positions, so that it can recycle the proper row views.

Given what you've posted, your implementation will probably look something like this:

```
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_DEFAULT = 0;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO = 1;

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // return a value between zero (inclusive) and the total item type count (exclusive)
    if (contents.get(position).content_type_id == 2) {
        return VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO;
    }
    return VIEW_TYPE_DEFAULT:
}
```

You can then check the view type again inside of `getView()`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if (type == VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        return buildVideoRow(position, convertView, parent);
    } else if (type == VIEW_TYPE_DEFAULT) {
        return buildDefaultRow(position, convertView, parent);
    }
    return null; // or throw an IllegalStateException, because something is wrong if you get here.
}

private View buildVideoRow(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    VideoViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView != null) {
        holder = (VideoViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } else {
        convertView = ... // inflate row here
        // set the tag, etc.
    }
    ... // bind views here
    return convertView;
}

private View buildDefaultRow(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // similar implementation as buildVideoRow()
}
```

Comment: thanks for your anwser, I understood, but the problem in my code, the contents list is  initiated in a CallBack() so I get a null reference exception in getItemVIewType with contents.get(i). the contents list is initiated in the buildVideoRow inside a onSuccess method of callback :/ do you have an idea how to solve this ?

Comment: @AymaneBo Load your data first before trying to show it in a list, or load the part of it that can determine the row type and load the rest later. The adater should not be responsible for loading the list; do that in your Activity or Fragment and then pass the loaded list to the adapter, calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` if you need to in order to refresh the ListView.